# Scala pop stack equivalent

Tags: scala, stack

I need to sequentially group rows of similar (by id) information from about 20 lists of lists. In SQL that would be called a `join`.

Towards this end I'd like to pop elements from the head of a sorted list based on id equality, add them to the current row and leave the rest for later processing.

A contrived example for such a pop for a singe list (or table if you wish) will be the following:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack

val ss = Stack(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

@annotation.tailrec
def retAll(ss: Stack[Int], x: Int, out: List[Int] = List()): List[Int] = {
    if (ss.head == x) {
        val h = ss.pop
        retAll(ss, x, h +: out)
    }
    else out
}

println(retAll(ss, 1))
println(ss)

// List(1, 1)
// Stack(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

which means that next time I'll retrieve `2` from the head of the stack left.

I'm wondering if there exists a more idiomatic or efficient approach to obtain the same result and, what is more important, if this construct can be parallelized later, through `Futures` eg, given `ss` is mutable?

Comment: A mutable non thread safe collection cannot safely be used concurrently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you just use a `List`, and use the efficiency `list.head` (in my example hidden inside `span`) be your pop operation?

For thread-safety as you mutate the reference, you might just wrap it in `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference`.

```scala
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference

val ss = AtomicReference(List(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))

def retAll(stack: AtomicReference[List[Int]], x: Int): List[Int] = {
    val ( popped, remainder ) = stack.get.span(_ == x)     
    if (popped.nonEmpty) stack.set(remainder)
    popped
}

println(retAll(ss, 1))
println(ss)

// List(1, 1)
// List(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

---

@GaëlJ makes a good point in the comments. Even though the reference is atomic, the get and set are distinct operations, and concurrent threads could interleave them to bad effect.

Probably the surest way to deal with thread safety here is to keep all access to and mutation of the list behind a lock with old-school synchronization. That said, if `retAll` is the only operation that will access the list, or if you are careful to do a similar work with respect to all other operations, a more correct version might be:

```scala
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference

val ss = AtomicReference(List(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))

def retAll(stack: AtomicReference[List[Int]], x: Int): List[Int] = {
    var out : List[Int] = null // var in a single-threaded local context is okay
    stack.updateAndGet { list =>
      val ( popped, remainder ) = list.span(_ == x)
      out = popped
      remainder
    }
    out
}

println(retAll(ss, 1))
println(ss)

// List(1, 1)
// List(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

It's a bit less elegant than the original-but-not-quite-thread-safe solution.

---

Here's an old-school sync'ed version:

```scala
class QueueManager {
  // protected by this' lock
  private var ss = List(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

  def current : List[Int] = this.synchronized(ss)

  def retAll(x: Int): List[Int] = this.synchronized {
    val ( popped, remainder ) = ss.span(_ == x)
    this.ss = remainder
    popped
  }
}

val qm = new QueueManager
qm.synchronized {
  println(qm.retAll(1))
  println(qm.current)
}

// List(1, 1)
// List(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is my first time I see `AtomicReference`, so a question: if I go the suggested path. should I add something special to execution context as well or default global execution context just suffice?

Comment: The method is still not threadsafe because you `get` and `set` in two different operations. You'd need to use `getAndSet` in one shot.

Comment: @GaëlJ (I've added some more correct variations...)

Answer (score 1):

Before anything, I totally agree with what GaelJ mentioned in the comments. But `popWhile` on `mutable.Stack` basically does the same thing:

```scala
val whatever = ss.popWhile(_ == x)
println(whatever)
println(ss)

// List(1, 1)
// Stack(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Based on the example provided in your question, I can also suggest the following which doesn't mutate the stack:

```scala
val whatever = ss.dropWhile(_ < x).takeWhile(_ == x).toList
// ss wouldn't change
```

If you just want to perform a `group by` operation:

```scala
println(ss.toList.groupBy(identity))
// Map[Int, List[Int]] = HashMap(
  5 -> List(5),
  1 -> List(1, 1),
  6 -> List(6),
  9 -> List(9),
  2 -> List(2),
  7 -> List(7),
  3 -> List(3),
  8 -> List(8),
  4 -> List(4)
)
```